# Influxdb - Subtracting value from previous row, group by time

Tags: influxdb

Is it possible to get individual data from cumulative?

Output of the following query is

```
SELECT mean("value") FROM "statsd_value" WHERE "type_instance" = 'counts' AND time > now() - 5m GROUP BY time(10s) fill(none)

TimeStamp   Value
1463393810  0
1463393820  10
1463393830  23
1463393840  34
1463393850  67
1463393860  90
1463393870  104
```

Basically, the above data is cumulative data, I want to get individual data from that similar to this

```
TimeStamp   Value
1463393820  10
1463393830  13
1463393840  11
1463393850  33
1463393860  23
1463393870  14
```

Is it possible to form query to get data in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

InfluxQL provides a [difference](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/query_language/functions/#difference) function that will give you the functionality that you're looking for.

The query would look like this:

```
SELECT difference(mean("value")) FROM "statsd_value" WHERE "type_instance" = 'counts' AND time > now() - 5m GROUP BY time(10s) fill(none)

TimeStamp   Value
1463393820  10
1463393830  13
1463393840  11 
1463393850  33
1463393860  23
1463393870  14
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you